# How do I send my custom erc20 token from ethreum to arbitrum?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, ethereumjs, arbitrum

I am  trying to send my custom erc20 tokens from ethreum (testnet) to arbitrum(testnet) through arbitrum bridge. But not sure if I had to  map my token first or arbitrum bridge does that itself?

How do I map my tokens for arbitrum bridge.

[image: It's been like this for a long time]

Answer (score 1):

If your token does not exist on arbitrum testate and you send your tokens from ethereum, then arbitrum would first deploy the smart contract associated to the token and then transfers it to your wallet in L2. However the token address would differ in L2 than in L1.